# Setting up specs for podcast edit

Tags: editing, daw, podcasts

What is everything you consider when setting up the specs in your DAW to edit a brand new podcast?

(Especially now you'll have recordings in different specs... how do you decide what to make the full podcast in?)

Comment: You mean you have some mp3, some aac, some wav etc?

Comment: Yes, but also since we can't record interviews with high quality recorders during the pandemic I'm using recordings from iPhone voice memos, Squadcast, and other apps where the bit rate and khz really vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upsample them all to 24 or 32-bit 48kHz* WAV at or before import.

This will gain no 'new' quality but will enable more manipulation/plugins etc without losing anything further.

You then have the highest quality master you can achieve, which you can downsample afterwards to whatever broadcast structure you need.

*or 44.1 if you don't need video sync.